# why is not read File at SparkContext.textFile()

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2

Why can't I read the hadoop README?

[image: Spark REPL Image]

Comment: You seems to have forgotten to ask a question.

Comment: @cricket_007 this post is updated, please comment to me

Comment: Are you really paying for EC2 to learn Spark? That's a waste of money... Anyway, you still have no question. What makes you think the first line isn't blank?

Comment: I don't know.. ,I had execute to local OS and test is successes. therefore I want to migrate  local package to ec2

Comment: The spark code you have runs the same in ec2 vs locally. You should open that file outside of spark and verify the first line actually has some characters. And then you can worry about the WARN that is shown.

Comment: okay. I will check on. thank you

Comment: Personally, `sc.textFile("...").take(10)` would be more useful. But, again, the file could be empty.

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the solution for Spark 2.1.0

```
val appName = "Read Text File Example"
val master = "local[*]"

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster(master)

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()

val sp = spark.read.text("pathtofile/README.md")

sp.collect().foreach(println)
```